# Flutter - How to check TextFormField enabled state?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I access the boolean where when you tap on the `TextFormField`, it either is enabled or disabled (like the border)?

I want to change the color of the Label based on whether it is enabled.

Comment: you pass either true/false while defining TextFormield with property `enabled`. You can look for the same property to check if it is enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enabled Boolean property. If enabled=false it is disabled unless is it enabled by default the you should add enabled Border

```
TextFormField(
                  enabled: true,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(12),
                        ),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
                    disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(12),
                        ),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

the output like this

if the form is enabled
[image: if the form is enabled]

if the form is disabled
[image: if the form is disabled]